# Cannot connect to raspberry via putty after reboot/boot

Tags: remote, nextcloud

im running nextcloudpi on my raspberry 3 which is connected via ethernet to my router.
But if i boot/reboot the raspberry, i cannot connect to the cloud neither with putty to it, until i login as pi user directly with keyboard and monitor. If i do so, everything is fine.
Of course i tried sudo apt-get update and upgrade.
There is also an USB drive connected.

Is this a ssh issue or something like that?
And i really dont wanna reinstall the entire cloud. ^^

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is nextcloudpi?

Comment: Did you use the image or install it from a Buster image?  It sounds like the main program does not load automatically but is set to run in the user start up scripts.

Comment: @Ingo nextcloudpi is a image for the nextcloud (Open Source Cloud) with everything u need, e.g. the OS for  the raspberry, apache and so on.  So u just need to flash this image and configurate ur cloud.

Comment: @Andryoo i used the nextcloudpi image. I also enabled  the autologin but then there was no connection anymore. But now i diceded to reinstall everything and load my data from the backup, hope the issue will not be in the backup.

Comment: It is difficult to assist for a "custom" OS image, except there is one with experience using it also. But lets try. Does the image is based on an official OS, e.g. Raspbian Buster or Raspberry Pi OS?